# Add Ideal payment method to Learnpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, payment, payment-method

I am trying to have the IDEAL payment method in the learnpress plugin on wordpress. I found a page named payment-method.php but i have no clue how to do it. Here is the code

```
<?php if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; } ?>

<?php if ( $gateway instanceof LP_Gateway_Abstract ) : ?>

<?php if ( apply_filters( 'learn_press_display_payment_method', true, $gateway->id ) ) { ?>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input id="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" type="radio" class="input-radio" <?php checked( $selected, $gateway->id, true ); ?> name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( LP()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' ) == $gateway->id, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" />
            <?php echo( $gateway->get_title() ); ?>
        </label>
        <?php if ( ( $payment_form = $gateway->get_payment_form() ) || ( $payment_form = $gateway->get_description() ) ) { ?>
            <div class="payment-method-form payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>"><?php echo $payment_form; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php do_action( 'learn_press_display_payment_method_form', $gateway ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I found a plugin that works with Learnpress, the only problem is that it cost 32,23 a year per site. The plugin is named 'Pronamic iDEAL', more information can be found on there site;

https://www.pronamic.nl/wordpress/plugins/pronamic-ideal/

Hope it did help you some how. There may be a free solution but I haven't found it yet. So if anybody does please let me know.